# When coming out of sleep mode (suspend), the screen turns to static

Tags: drivers, suspend

When coming out of sleep mode (suspend), the screen turns to static.

I'm running Ubunutu on a Macbook Pro 2009 17". The issue occurs upon closing and opening the lid.

This problem is *not* present with a fresh install of Ubuntu version 18.04. The issue becomes apparent after updating or installing later versions. I suspect its the video drivers as I'm able to install other updates without the issue.

I would be fine with just sticking to this version, but later video drivers are able to play games at a significantly faster speed.

Thanks!